# Use addEventListener to change display style

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn addEventListener, but somehow it doesn't work. Console doesn't show any error either.

So, I have these sections:

```
<section id="media_image-4" class="widget widget_media_image">
    <div class="widget-wrap">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="https://domains/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/image-150x150.jpg" class="image wp-image-41  attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" sizes="(max-width: 150px) 100vw, 150px" />
    </div>
</section>

<section id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
    <div class="widget-wrap"><div class="textwidget">
        <p id="sublinks">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-833" src="https://domains/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/icon-link.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" data-sitemapexclude="true" />
        </p>
    </div></div>
</section>
```

By default, the section id media_image-4 is hidden with css "display: none". I would like it's shown when I click to icon-link.png image. So, I created an external javascript, and called it. The file is:

```
var mID = document.getElementById ("sublinks");
mID.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("media_image-4");
    if ( x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "") {
        x.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "";
    }
}, false);
```

Am I doing something wrongly? What should I do to get media_image-4 shown?
Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: I think that you might not have a display style on that element at all. You could add this: `if ( x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "" || !x.style.display) {`. If that doesn't work, I recommend `console.log()`ing x.style.display in the event listener so you can see what it is, then modify your script based on that.

Comment: Is your event handler getting executed? You can check this by going into your browser's development tools (F12), going to the debugger and adding a breakpoint to the line that says `var x = document.getElementById('media_image-4');`. Then click the image again. If the code doesn't pause there, you may need to change the event listener to the actual image instead of the `p` around it.

Comment: When the event listener runs for the first time, `x.style.display` doesn't exist yet. Therefore it is set to `""` which is not a valid value for `style`. On the next click, `x.style.display == ""` is true so it gets set to `display: inline-block`, and being very similar to "inline" here, you don't notice it. The next click changes it to `""` again, etc.

Comment: `x.style.display = "";` does not hide it, it shows it

Comment: Live code example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k1bda4fn/

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. It turns out that Chrome cached the javascript file. I needed to use SHIFT when reload, then the new javascript code could work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
else {
    x.style.display = "";
}
```

write

```
else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

otherwise everything is ok

But better solve it through specified class

CSS:

```
#media_image-4 {
   display: none;
}

#media_image-4.showMe {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

and JS code

```
document.getElementById ("sublinks").addEventListener ("click", () => {
   document.getElementById("media_image-4").classList.toggle('showMe')
}, false);
```